# XCode custom working directory has no effect

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm building a Polycode 3D application on multiple platforms. While I can set the debugging working directory fine from Visual Studio, running the application in debug while in Xcode seems to ignore my custom working directory, meaning I can't load files.

My Xcode project has one scheme (PolycodeTemplate) and I've gone into Edit Scheme -> Run -> Working Directory and changed this to `$(SRCROOT)/../working` (this points to my working directory that's shared between the Windows and Mac projects). However, getting the current directory from within the application when it's running in the debugger returns `/Users/vesper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolycodeTemplate-fidrocibjuhrchbsabtwqhwnxfuk/Build/Products/Debug/PolycodeTemplate.app/Contents/Resources` which is not the correct directory.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd rather not set the directory manually through code because it might end up being different on different platforms.

Comment: What sort of program is it?

Comment: @trojanfoe has the right of it. Basically, applications on macs are bundled into an app bundle. You need to make sure you're setting this folder to be exported along with your project. Otherwise, it won't exist in your app bundle.

Comment: It's a 64-bit standard desktop application. Polycode uses an Objective-C/C++ entry point for Mac and I've used it to then move into more platform-agnostic C++ code.

Comment: So it's an app, as opposed to a command-line utility?

Comment: `/PolycodeTemplate.app` seems to think so....

Comment: Of course.  My understanding was that you cannot rely on the working directory of a `.app` to be anything in particular.  However if that's the case I don't know why the debugger allows you to set the *working directory*.  Regardless, you'll need to provide the ability to pass the directory to the app so it can change to the *working directory* itself, or instead pass the full path of these files to the app.

Comment: OK, that all makes sense. Is there a way to have Xcode copy any content from a given folder into the app bundle? I know you can specify individual files to copy in, but it'd be quite tedious to have to change this list manually whenever a file was added to or removed from the folder (which at the moment, as I'm working on resource files, is pretty often).